# Application in Android: when I click on the on/off button the application does not work

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a simple application in Android Studio for managing a device connected via wifi using the Volley library. Put simply, I want that when I click on the On button the device turns on and consequently shows me an image of a light bulb on, while when I click on the Off button the device must turn off and show me an image of a light bulb off on the screen.
After that, when I run the application and click on the button nothing happens. I'm not getting any errors.

```js
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    SwitchCompat switchButton;
    LinearLayout imageViewLight;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    TextView buttonState;
    private StringRequest mStringRequest;
    private String url = "http://192.168.130.15:8081/zeroconf/switch";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        switchButton=findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
        imageViewLight=findViewById(R.id.linearL);
        TextView buttonState;
        buttonState = findViewById(R.id.buttonState);

        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sendAndRequestResponse();                
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendAndRequestResponse() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                TextView myTextView;
                if (switchButton.isChecked()) {
                    imageViewLight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light__02);
                    buttonState.setText("State : ON");
                } else {
                    imageViewLight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light__01);
                    buttonState.setText("State : OFF");
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.i(TAG,"Error :" + error.toString());
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);  

    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: To troubleshoot this, place "Log.i" statements throughout your code to understand the flow and have them show the state of your variables. Alternatively, you can set a breakpoint and use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti How do I get the stacktrace? I am a beginner unfortunately

Comment: @shagberg How do I insert the "Log.i" instructions into the code? This is the first time I've done this

Comment: @elfuso Here is an example: Log.i(MainActivity, "This is switchButton status: " + switchButton.isChecked());     Also, to get the stacktrace, review the "Logcat" tab at the bottom of your Android Studio application.